# Kotlin how does the inbuilt println function look like?

Tags: kotlin

I've been just wondering, is there a way to check how does the kotlin inbuild functions look like? (for example println()). As far as i know the inbuilt functions like println come to us ready-to-use, but they had to be written somehow. Can i see the source code of the entire function?

Comment: just Ctrl+Click it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see source code of Kotlin functions in docs.

println() source code:

```
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun println(message: CharArray) {
    System.out.println(message)
}
```

[println() docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/println.html) *(Click "JVM Source" under function's name)*

*P.S. Ctrl+Click in code does not always display the logic of the source code.*